# Fade in div once user scrolls past element

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problem:

I'm trying to fadeIn and fadeOut `div class="audioBox"` once the user scrolls past the header. What I have seems to work fine, except for when the page is loaded and I'm already past the 835px height of the header/

**Q: What I'm seeing is when I scroll the `audioBox` quickly fades in and then fades out, despite `scroll >= header` How do I prevent this from happening?**

### scripts.js

```
// If the reader scrolls past header, show audioBox
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var header = $("header").height();

if (scroll >= header) {
    $(".audioBox").fadeIn();
} else if (scroll <= header) {
    $(".audioBox").fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: What I see there is you have some collision in the equality. For example when header==scroll I see your code is triggering both actions at the same time. Would be better if you avoid using >= and <= and just use < and >.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried implementing what you're describing in jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/3wqfp2ch/1/.

I'd approach it a bit differently, based on the following ideas:

- I personally prefer letting CSS take care of visual stuff via classes, and let jQuery take the simple responsibility of controlling when the classes should be added/removed. I think it makes for a better relationship between the two systems and allows each to do their thing better & more neatly.
- I didn't see where you were listening for scroll events on the window, which is essential for figuring out whether a user's scroll position is before or after the header, so have included this in my code
- I don't think we need multiple if conditions - there's just one question: "Is the scroll position greater than the header height?".

Here's the JS:

```js
var headerHeight = $("header").height();
var audioBox = $('#audioBox');

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollPosition > headerHeight) {
    audioBox.addClass('is-visible');
  } else {
    audioBox.removeClass('is-visible');
  }
});
```

Check out my fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/3wqfp2ch/1/ for the HTML & CSS that this relates to, and the working demo putting it all together.

I can't test whether this suffers from the same issue regarding you loading at a point already past the header height from jsfiddle unfortunately, but I wouldn't be expecting the behaviour you described using the code above.

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Great news, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.fadeIn()` or `.fadeOut()` **all the time** and having an overlap in the conditions might be the problem.

Try this:

```
// If the reader scrolls past header, show audioBox
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var header = $("header").offset().top + $("header").height(); // should include the header's offset as well

if (scroll >= header) {
    $(".audioBox:hidden").fadeIn();
} else if (scroll < header) {
    $(".audioBox:visible").fadeOut();
}
```